# Java/Android - Error loading ArrayList as Object from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Been trying to solve this Firebase loading arraylist problem for a while now but no idea how to get it solved.

**Object Class**

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String ISBN;
    private String photo;
    private String ownerEmail;
    private String ownerID;
    private String BookID;
    private Date returnDate;
    private Status status;
    private String borrowerID;

    public Book(){}
    public Book(String title, String author, String ISBN, String photo, String ownerEmail, String ownerID) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.ownerEmail = ownerEmail;
        this.ownerID = ownerID;
        this.status = Status.Available;
        if(this.BookID == null || this.BookID.isEmpty())
            this.BookID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
    public enum Status{
        Available,
        Requested,
        Accepted,
        Borrowed
    }
```

I have getter and setter for all the variables, and what I'm doing is load this information from **firebase using the code:**

```
 public void loadMyBookFromFirebase(){
        final ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(this.userID).child("myBooks");
        userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("testing","books" + dataSnapshot.toString());
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    try {
                        for (DataSnapshot books : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Book book = dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);
                            Log.d("testing","books" + book.getAuthor());
                            //load book into ListView
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("testing","Error: ", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }
```

**this is my firebase database** [firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS9vm.png)
i keep getting a
    Can't convert object of type `java.util.ArrayList` to type `com.example.cmput301w19t15.Book`

error on the line `Book book = dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);`
im not sure why i am getting the convert object error, i do not want to search for individual variables and set them, which defeat the purpose of the object class

I would really like some insight on this

Comment: Please upload the database structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Book book = dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);
```

to

```
Book book = books.getValue(Book.class);
```

You need to get the data from the `books` object and not from the `dataSnapshot` object.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was an oversight, did not notice at all